# combining osm data (downloaded with osmdata package) in a existing shapefile map ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap, shapefile

I want to plot a map using OSM Data. The needed data can be downloaded easily with the `osmdata`-R-package. Unfortunately for my region not all data is available in OSM. Therefor I downloaded a shapefile of the Region with the administrative boundaries I am interessed in. My problem is, that I cant plot the shapefile information together with the OSM information in one plot.

My Workflow:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(rgeos)
library(osmdata)
library(sf)



# Download shapefile from Leipzig with "Ortteile" (engl. urban districts)
https://gruenlink.de/1py4
# import Ortsteile Leipzigs
lpz_ot <- readOGR("ot.shp")
names(lpz_ot)
# convert spatial object to a ggplot ready data frame
lpz_ot_df <- tidy(lpz_ot,OT = "id")
# make sure the shapefile attribute table has an id column
lpz_ot$id <- rownames(lpz_ot@data)
# join the attribute table from the spatial object to the new data frame
lpz_ot_df <- lpz_ot_df %>%
  left_join(lpz_ot@data,by = "id")
# check names
names(lpz_ot_df)


# Download interessting OSM Data (e.g. railways and tramlines)
#bounding box Leipzig
lpz_box <- opq(bbox = 'Leipzig')
# Plygon for Leipzig
lpz_poly <- getbb(place_name = c("Leipzig"),format_out = "polygon")
# railways and tramlines in Leipzig (in bounding box)
sv <- lpz_box%>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "railway", value = c("tram","rail")) %>%
  osmdata_sf() 
# railways and tramlines in Leipzig (within administrative boundaries of Leipzig)
svt <-  trim_osmdata (sv,lpz_poly,exclude =TRUE)
```

I can easily plot the shape-file or the osmdata with ggplot. But I can't plot both in one plot. What is my error in reasining?

My plot code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = lpz_ot_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,color="black"))+
  geom_sf(data = svt$osm_lines, aes(color = railway),size=1.3) +
  theme_void() +
  guides(color = FALSE)+
  labs(title ="Urban districts in Leipzigs (with railwaynet)")
```

To test it, just comment out `geom_path()` or the `geom_sf()` lines.

I think, it has something to do with the coordiates, but I dont know how to assign the correct coordiates.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has indeed to do with the coordinate systems. I recommend you to use `sf` also to read the `ot.shp` into R, and then change the coordinate system. That will replace the first part of your code (before downloading OSM data) with:

```
lpz_ot = st_read('ot.shp') %>% st_transform(crs = 4326)
```

To plot it, just replace the `geom_path` line on your ggplot code with:

```
geom_sf(data = lpz_ot)
```